# Urysohn's Lemma from RCA Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

[image]

I found out the proof of Urysohn's Lemma from Rudin's book but I have couple questions which I am not able to answer.

**1)** Why Rudin wrote that "in terms of characteristic functions, the conclusion asserts the existence of a *continuous function* $f$ which satisfies inequalities $\chi_K\leqslant f \leqslant \chi_V$"?

But how to conclude from here that $f$ has *compact support* and it *lies* in $V$? I concluded from $\chi_K\leqslant f \leqslant \chi_V$ that $f=1$ on $K$, $f=0$ on $V^c$. But what we can say about $f$ on $V-K$?

**2)** Why he mentioned *semicontinuous* functions? I totally didn't understand this line.

**3)** Each $f_r(x), g_s(x)$ are lower semicontinuous (LSC) and upper semicontinuous (USC), respectively. Right? If $r=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $f_r$ is constant function $\Rightarrow$ $f_r$ is LSC. If $r>0$ then $f_r(x)=rh_r(x)$ where $h_r$ is the indicator of open set $\Rightarrow$ $h_r$ is LSC $\Rightarrow$ $f_r$ is LSC. If $s\in \{0,1\}$ then $g_s$ is USC since it's indicator of closed or constant function, respectively. If $s\in (0,1)$ then $g_s(x)=s+(1-s)h_s(x)$ where $h_s$ is the indicator of closed set.

**4)** If $x\in K$ then $x\in V_r$ for all $r$ $\Rightarrow$ $f_r(x)=1$ $\Rightarrow$ $f(x)=1$. Am I right? Note that Rudin never mentioned that $K\subset V_r$ for any  $r$.

**5)** What's motivation to show that $f=g$? I suspect that if $f=g$ then $f$ is simultaneously LSC and USC $\Rightarrow$ $f$ is continuous. Right?

Comment: 1) $f$ has this property; this property itself doesn't mean $f$ is compactly supported. 2) for your (or maybe his) interest. 3) 4) 5) right. Rudin doesn't mention a lot of things.

Comment: @QiyuWen, Your remark about 1) I didn't understand. He emphasized that exists *continuous* function. No words about that it's function with compact support which lies in $V$.

Comment: @QiyuWen, Maybe these properties follows from inequality $1_K\leqslant f\leqslant 1_V$?

Comment: That $f$ has compact support is because $\mathrm{supp} f \subset \bar{V}_0$. The inequalities are not enough to conclude that.

Comment: @QiyuWen, I guess that there is some misunderstanding between our words. Sorry but look Rudin wrote that assertion of theorem is equivalent to existence of CONTINUOUS function $f$ with $1_K\leqslant f\leqslant 1_V$. Right? He doesn't mention nothing about that $f$ has compact support and that this support lies in $V$. I hope that you understood me.

Comment: @QiyuWen, He didn't write "function from $C_c(X)$". He wrote CONTINUOUS function.

Comment: "But how to conclude from here that $f$ has compact support and it lies in $V$?" I just told you how, it's not concluded from this statement. Is Urysohn's lemma equivalent to those inequalities? No. Neither is Rudin saying it is. He's saying Urysohn's lemma implies the inequalities. He's not saying the existence of a function with such inequalities implies Urysohn's lemma, and you should not think so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41356/discussion-between-rfz-and-qiyu-wen).

Comment: @QiyuWen, Hi! Can we talk in chat please?

Answer (score 0):

So $K$ and $V$ are given to us. By local compactness there exists a $U$ open satisying $K\subset U\subset \bar U\subset V$. Now apply the lemma to the pair $K,U$ to produce a (compactly supported) continuous function $f$. Since $\{x:f(x)\neq 0\}\subset U$ it follows that the support of $f$ lies in $\bar U$ and hence in $V$.